# Save HTMLFile ComObject to file in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

After loading a html file using

```
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$content = $(Get-Content $path -raw)
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)
```

I have manipulated the `$html` object and now want to save it to another file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just started using the HTMLFile COM object, but I believe that `$html.documentElement.outerHTML` should be a string containing the entire document including the opening `<html>` tag, but not the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.  You can access `$html.doctype` or just shove in a `<!DOCTYPE html>` yourself, then you should wind up with a valid page on disk.